# How did Chandra (moon) get a Rabbit Mark on it?

Tags: animals, chandra

Chandra is called **"Shashaanka" - "Shasha (Rabbit) + Anka (Mark)" - "One who has mark of a rabbit"**.

And it is quite evident also, we see a vague Rabbit shaped mark on the moon.

For example -
[image: Rabbit mark]

[image: Moon's picture]

[image: Rabbit mark]

In out Scriptures Moon is called
1. Shashaanka (शशाङ्क) - one having mark of rabbit
2. Shashee (शशी)- one who has rabbit or rabbit like
3. Shashabrit (शशभृत्) - one who holds rabbit (mark)
4. Shashabindu (शशबिन्दु) - one who has mark of rabbit
5. Shashadhara (शशधर) - one who holds a rabbit (mark)

How did this mark come on moon?

Comment: Is Chandra also known as Mriganko? If yes then there should be a mark of deer too.. BTW Chandra is linked with both these animals-deer and rabbit.

Comment: "And it is quite evident also, we see a vague Rabbit shaped mark on the moon". No it is not evident. People see all kinds of shapes onto the moon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Brahma Vaivarta Puraana , Prakriti Khanda , Chapter 58

After stealing Taaraa wife of Brihaspati, Chandra went to refuge of Shukra Deva the Guru of Asuras.

There,

> बभूव शरणापन्नो भीतो दैत्येषु चन्द्रमाः ।
>   तेजस्विनि तथा शुक्रे तेषां च बलिनां गुरौ ॥ ४० ॥
>   अभयं च ददौ तस्मै कृपया भृगुनन्दनः ।
>   गुरुं जहास देवानां सुविपक्षं बृहस्पतिम् ॥ ४१ ॥
>   सभायां जहसुर्हृष्टा बलिनो दितिनन्दनाः ।
>   अभयं च ददुस्तस्मै भीताय च कलङ्किने ॥ ४२ ॥
>   **सतीसतीत्वध्वंसेन पापिष्ठचन्द्रमण्डले ।
>
>   बभूव शशरूपं च कलंकं निर्मले मलम् ॥ ४३ ॥**
>
> The frightened Chandramaa got refuge in the Daityas and the resplendent Shukra Deva who is Guru of those powerful Daityas. 40.
>   Shukra the son of Bhrigu, out of his mercy told Chandra "Do not fear" ,
>   and laughed at the Guru of Devas, Brihaspati, who is the fast opposition of Shukra. 41 .
>   Then all the Daityas, sons of Diti who are valourous and powerful also laughed in that court,
>   and told Chandra not to fear, who was frightened as well as defamed. 42  .
>   **Due to destroying the purity of pious lady (Taaraa) an impure spot mark in Shape of Rabbit came on the pure Sphere of Moon who had committed a sin. 43 .**

This is the reason we see a vague Rabbit mark on Moon Sphere (Chandra Mandala).

Comment: So u already knew the answer while posting the Q?

Comment: @Rickross Haha yes.